# qemu-system-i386: Could not load snapshot for icount replay

Tags: qemu, snapshot

I'd like to use QEMU for recording/replaying execution. However, the replaying does not work as described in the [manual](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/replay.html):

```bash
$ qemu-system-i386 \
-icount shift=auto,rr=record,rrfile=record.bin,rrsnapshot=snap1 \
-drive file=boot.qcow2,if=none,snapshot=on,id=img-direct \
-drive driver=blkreplay,if=none,image=img-direct,id=img-blkreplay \
-device ide-hd,drive=img-blkreplay \
-net none
```

```
$ qemu-system-i386 \
-icount shift=auto,rr=replay,rrfile=record.bin,rrsnapshot=snap1 \
-drive file=boot.qcow2,if=none,snapshot=on,id=img-direct \
-drive driver=blkreplay,if=none,image=img-direct,id=img-blkreplay \
-device ide-hd,drive=img-blkreplay \
-net none
qemu-system-i386: Snapshot 'snap1' does not exist in one or more devices
qemu-system-i386: Could not load snapshot for icount replay
```

Snapshots made with `savevm xyz` can not be found either.

How do I get replaying to work?

QEMU version: 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

That example isn't direct from the manual because you have added rrsnapshot and it is correctly reporting that "snap1" doesn't exist. Snapshots are manually created in replay mode my using the "savevm" command via HMP/QMP and can be used to jump back to a given execution state.